# Angular translate on custom attributes

Tags: angular, angular-translate, custom-attribute

I have a switch widget which uses custom data attribute value to label itself.

```css
.switch.switch-text .switch-label::before {
  right: 1px;
  color: #c2cfd6;
  content: attr(data-hide);
  }
  
  .switch.switch-text .switch-label::after {
  left: 1px;
  color: #c2cfd6;
  content: attr(data-show);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch.switch-text .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch.switch-text .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch switch-text switch-pill switch-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
                            <span class="switch-label" attr.data-show="{{GLOBALS.ACTIONS.SHOW | translate}}" attr.data-hide="{{GLOBALS.ACTIONS.HIDE | translate}}"></span>
                            <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                        </label>
```

But it just does not work. I have looked at different answers relating to similar problem but some says it works some says it doesn't. If I user without attr. in front I get a binding error anyway since it does not recognise the attribute.

How can I translate the value of custom attribute using angular translate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have a typo in your template. Your have to use a one way data binding syntax to update attributes "data-show" with the translated value. If you omit the bracket then you just create a static "`attr.data-show`" attribute whom value is "`{{GLOBALS.ACTIONS.SHOW | translate}}`"

Your code produces :

```
<span class="switch-label" attr.data-show="{{GLOBALS.ACTIONS.SHOW | translate}}" attr.data-hide="{{GLOBALS.ACTIONS.HIDE | translate}}"></span>
```

The corrected template syntax is :

```
  <label class="switch switch-text switch-pill switch-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
        <span class="switch-label" [attr.data-show]="'GLOBALS.ACTIONS.SHOW' | translate" [attr.data-hide]="'GLOBALS.ACTIONS.HIDE' | translate"></span>
        <span class="switch-handle"></span>
   </label>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't get an error so its a good thing. But still no text appearing. There is nothing in my .ts file do I have to define those? We normally include translate and it works for strings. But in this case will angular not pick up these attributes bf default?

Comment: Ok I think I realised I need to create directive decorative too. I just checked what it needs. I am just new to this angular 2+ and also trying to change another developer's code to accommodate switch checkbox.

Comment: @tekin your CSS directive has opacity: 0. Did you try to remove this?

Comment: Right I couldn't get that one , because these are not really custom attributes but html data- attributes so how can I bind them from component side?

Comment: Hi Pierre, sorry the CSS is not complete it transitions opacity according to which message need to be shown, one becomes 1 the other becomes 0. But will check if both gets 0.

Comment: Just added  more on css so yes it is 0 and 1 when it is checked.

Comment: I can see the problem the attributes do not show on the DOM at all. so CSS can not do anything really.

Comment: Oops ok got it  it needs single quotes also "'GLOBALS.ACTIONS.SHOW' | translate" no need for extra directive in component.

Comment: Pierre I marked as correct but can you add the single quotes around translate keys please, it didn't let me (less than 6 characters editing) you might just give it a better presentation, and thanks I already have extra translation file that worked fine...

Comment: I followed that code but I dont any text. Here is my code: class="tree-label" [attr.data-show]="'Forecast' | translate".    Css: .tree-label {
                cursor: pointer;
                content: attr(data-show);
            }